# Apache Fop external graphic with PDF show all pages

Tags: xml, xslt, apache-fop

When I include a PDF file with the PDF images plugin, I only see the first page. You can include a page number in the src attribute, but I don't know how many pages there are in the pdf to include.
Is there a way to include all pages?

Comment: Could you include the `<fo:external-*` tag you're using ?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6076425/how-to-embed-external-pdf-txt-file-into-another-using-xsl-fo